# Cannot read my Json file to draw a line chart using D3.js code

Tags: jquery, css, json, svg, linechart

This code is programmed by js to draw a line chart using D3 Libarary. I face an error which the console shows that a (TypeError: e is undefined)) related to the d3.v3.min.js:1 and when I click on the Debbuger tap of firefox it shows this line of data

!function(){function n(n,t){return t>n?-1:n>t?1:n>=t?0:0/0}function t(n){return null!=n&&!isNaN(n)}function e(n){return{left:function(t,e,r,u){for(arguments.length<3&&(r=0),arguments.length<4&&(u=t.length);u>r;){var i=r+u>>>1;n(t[i],e)<0?r=i+1:u=i}return
and this line goes longer !!!

This is my Json file

```
    {
"Id": 2,
"Name": "ukraine",
"Occurrences": [
    {
        "OccurrenceDate": "Jan 2000",
        "OccurrenceFrequency": 136
    },
    {
        "OccurrenceDate": "Feb 2000",
        "OccurrenceFrequency": 2
    },
    {
        "OccurrenceDate": "Mar 2000",
        "OccurrenceFrequency": 89
    }
   ]}
```

This is my Code , and my code is to make a line chart based on the date

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>``
<script>

    var margin = { top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parse = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

    // Scales and axes. Note the inverted domain for the y-scale: bigger is up!

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-height).tickSubdivide(true),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(4).orient("right");

    // An area generator, for the light fill.

    var area = d3.svg.area()
   .interpolate("monotone")
   .x(function (d) { return x(d.OccurrenceDate); })
   .y0(height)
   .y1(function (d) { return y(d.OccurrenceFrequency); });

    // A line generator, for the dark stroke.

    var line = d3.svg.line()
   .interpolate("monotone")
   .x(function (d) { return x(d.OccurrenceDate); })
   .y(function (d) { return y(d.OccurrenceFrequency); });

    d3.json("readme.json", type, function (error, data) {

        // Filter to one Name; ukraine.

        var values = data.filter(function (d) {
            return d.Name == "ukraine";
        });

        // Compute the minimum and maximum date, and the maximum OccurrenceFrequency.

        x.domain([values[0].OccurrenceDate, values[values.length - 1].OccurrenceDate]);
        y.domain([0, d3.max(values, function (d) { return d.OccurrenceFrequency; })]).nice();

        // Add an SVG element with the desired dimensions and margin.

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
       .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
       .append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
       .on("click", click);

        // Add the clip path.

        svg.append("clipPath")
       .attr("id", "clip")
       .append("rect")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height);

        // Add the area path.

        svg.append("path")
       .attr("class", "area")
       .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
       .attr("d", area(values));

        // Add the x-axis.

        svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "x axis")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
       .call(xAxis);

        // Add the y-axis.

        svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
       .call(yAxis);

        // Add the line path.

        svg.append("path")
       .attr("class", "line")
       .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
       .attr("d", line(values));

        // Add a small label for the name.

        svg.append("text")
       .attr("x", width - 6)
       .attr("y", height - 6)
       .style("text-anchor", "end")
       .text(values[0].Name);

        // On click, update the x-axis.

        function click() {
            var n = values.length - 1,
             i = Math.floor(Math.random() * n / 2),
             j = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * n / 2) + 1;
            x.domain([values[i].OccurrenceDate, values[j].OccurrenceDate]);
            var t = svg.transition().duration(750);
            t.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
            t.select(".area").attr("d", area(values));
            t.select(".line").attr("d", line(values));
        }
    });

    // Parse dates and numbers. We assume values are sorted by date.

    function type(d) {
        d.OccurrenceDate = parse(d.OccurrenceDate);
        d.OccurrenceFrequency = +d.OccurrenceFrequency;
        return d;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: why do you wrap your JSON in (...); and not keep it in { ... } only?

Comment: At which line does the message "e is undefined" occurs? I can't find a variable called 'e' in your code.

Comment: No spcific line it said in the conslo ((TypeError: e is undefined))

Comment: Your debugger conplains about a long long 'line 1' because the file is minified. Try to use regular "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" without minification. Maybe this points us to a (readable) piece of d3 function for a better understanding.

Comment: Webserver: d3.json will do a GET request. Do you have your files on a (local) webserver or just opened from a folder from your windows/mac/linux? Last one can not handle webserver requests and thereby will not load files in advance.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work . Now it showes this (TypeError: string is undefined)

Comment: I don't know how to do that !! and I have the file on my computer . I use a windows 8

Comment: With just local files you can use _d3.data=[ ... ]_


`var data = [{
"Id": 2,
"Name": "ukraine",
"Occurrences": [
    {
        "OccurrenceDate": "Jan 2000",
        "OccurrenceFrequency": 136
    },
    {
        "OccurrenceDate": "Feb 2000",
        "OccurrenceFrequency": 2
    },
    {
        "OccurrenceDate": "Mar 2000",
        "OccurrenceFrequency": 89
    }
   ]}];
   //", function(error, data) {
// Filter to one Name; ukraine.

// remove curly brace from old function
 //});
// Parse dates...`


But now you may have to check your variables like d.OccurrenceDate

Comment: but by doing this my graph is static. The point of my graph is to be dynamic ... My json file will be updated by another API , and then , the graph will visualise the date.

Comment: [d3.json(url, callback) only handles 2 attributes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests), not a 3 as in your code. 

Maybe therefor console shows:
_d3_time_parse d3.v3.js:2465_
_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined d3.v3.js:2465_
I post back, and keep trying to have it running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use d3.json() you need to **set up a webserver**. That's easy. 
Opening files from windows explorer will show static content, but can not handle loading more files via 'HTTP GET'. I guess, that 'string is undefined' is caused, as json file is not loaded and therefore the string inside d3.json is not only empty but undefined.

- Download [XAMPP - apache webserver, database etc](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) bundled in one simple to install package.
- Place the HTML and JSON files in the 'htdocs' folder. Look for the folder called 'htdocs' inside your installation path (e.g. C:\xamppfiles\htdocs).
- Start the webserver by the xampp control center.
- In your webbrowser navigate to *localhost/nameOfTheHtmlFile.html*
- Post a reply, what you see and what error may be shown.

Comment: Something wrong , I culdn't download xampp. Can you share me a link to download it .

Comment: Here the direct download link to [XAMPP for Windows 
v1.8.3 (PHP 5.5.11)](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.3/xampp-win32-1.8.3-4-VC11-installer.exe)

Comment: It's doesn't work . I connect it using another wbserver . I still face same problem !!!!

Comment: check out the new answer with a working graph for data of 'ukraine'

Answer (score 0):

If it should look something like this, keep on reading the 4 tipps.
[image]

I did a few updates:

**JSON needs to be an array**, so surround it with [    ] if possible (i think, d3 provides some object-to-array converter)

```
[{
"Id": 2,
"Name": "ukraine",
"Occurrences": [... ]
}] // brackets are important
```

**d3.json(url, callbackFunction)**
This only takes two arguments, not three.

```
d3.json( "soD3Question.json", function ( data ) { ... });
```

**parse time format**
You can not add this function to d3.json. You could iterate over the array and alternate the values by your self.

```
var parse = d3.time.format( "%b %Y" ).parse;
var parseAllDates = function (  ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < data[0].Occurrences.length; i++ ) {
        data[0].Occurrences[i].OccurrenceDate = parse( data[0].Occurrences[i].OccurrenceDate );
    }
}

d3.json( "soD3Question.json", function ( jsonData ) {
        data = jsonData;
        parseAllDates( ); // call date parser
        ...
```

**SVG colors** I just could guess, as there is no stylesheet provided and image contains of 3 black overlapping pathes, colors e.g.

```
path.domain{ fill: lightgrey; }
path.line{ fill: white;}
path.area{ fill: grey; }
```

---------- so here comes the full code (don't forget brackets in json-file)-----------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        path.domain {fill: lightgrey;}
        path.line {fill: white;}
        path.area {fill: grey;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var margin = { top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var data;
    var parse = d3.time.format( "%b %Y" ).parse;
    var parseAllDates = function () {
        for ( var i = 0; i < data[0].Occurrences.length; i++ ) {
            data[0].Occurrences[i].OccurrenceDate = parse( data[0].Occurrences[i].OccurrenceDate );
        }
    }
    // Scales and axes. Note the inverted domain for the y-scale: bigger is up!

    var x = d3.time.scale().range( [0, width] ),
            y = d3.scale.linear().range( [height, 0] ),
            xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale( x ).tickSize( -height ).tickSubdivide( true ),
            yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale( y ).ticks( 4 ).orient( "right" );

    // An area generator, for the light fill.

    var area = d3.svg.area()
            .interpolate( "monotone" )
            .x( function ( d ) {
                return x( d.OccurrenceDate );
            } )
            .y0( height )
            .y1( function ( d ) {
                return y( d.OccurrenceFrequency );
            } );

    // A line generator, for the dark stroke.

    var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate( "monotone" )
            .x( function ( d ) {
                return x( d.OccurrenceDate );
            } )
            .y( function ( d ) {
                return y( d.OccurrenceFrequency );
            } );


    //    d3.json( "soD3Question.json", type, function ( error, data ) {
    d3.json( "soD3Question.json", function ( jsonData ) {
        data = jsonData;
        parseAllDates();
        // Filter to one Name; ukraine.

        var values = data.filter( function ( d ) {
            return d.Name == "ukraine";
        } );


        // Compute the minimum and maximum date, and the maximum OccurrenceFrequency.
        values = values[0].Occurrences;
        x.domain( [values[0].OccurrenceDate, values[values.length - 1].OccurrenceDate ] );
        y.domain( [0, d3.max( values, function ( d ) {
            return d.OccurrenceFrequency;
        } )] ).nice();

        // Add an SVG element with the desired dimensions and margin.

        var svg = d3.select( "body" ).append( "svg" )
                .attr( "width", width + margin.left + margin.right )
                .attr( "height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom )
                .append( "g" )
                .attr( "transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")" )
                .on( "click", click );

        // Add the clip path.

        svg.append( "clipPath" )
                .attr( "id", "clip" )
                .append( "rect" )
                .attr( "width", width )
                .attr( "height", height );

        // Add the x-axis.

        svg.append( "g" )
                .attr( "class", "x axis" )
                .attr( "transform", "translate(0," + height + ")" )
                .call( xAxis );

        // Add the y-axis.

        svg.append( "g" )
                .attr( "class", "y axis" )
                .attr( "transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)" )
                .call( yAxis );

        // Add the line path.

        svg.append( "path" )
                .attr( "class", "line" )
                .attr( "clip-path", "url(#clip)" )
                .attr( "d", line( values ) );

        // Add the area path.

        svg.append( "path" )
                .attr( "class", "area" )
//                .attr( "clip-path", "url(#clip)" ) // needs to be defined
                .attr( "d", area( values ) );

        // Add a small label for the name.
        svg.append( "text" )
                .attr( "x", width - 6 )
                .attr( "y", height - 6 )
                .style( "text-anchor", "end" )
                .text( values[0].Name );

        // On click, update the x-axis.

        function click() {
            var n = values.length - 1,
                    i = Math.floor( Math.random() * n / 2 ),
                    j = i + Math.floor( Math.random() * n / 2 ) + 1;
            x.domain( [values[i].OccurrenceDate, values[j].OccurrenceDate] );
            var t = svg.transition().duration( 750 );
            t.select( ".x.axis" ).call( xAxis );
            t.select( ".area" ).attr( "d", area( values ) );
            t.select( ".line" ).attr( "d", line( values ) );
        }
    } );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```